# Configuring Structure Map on Application_BeginRequest in Global.asax for specific user

Tags: asp.net-mvc, structuremap

I have a Foo and Foo1 classes which both implements IFoo. Default mapping for IFoo is Foo in StructureMap. But, for some users I would like to map IFoo to Foo1. I have a `if` block on `Application_BeginRequest` in *`Global.asax`* that maps IFoo to Foo1 for the specific user. But, whenever I do this all the user start to using Foo1 instead of Foo.

I tried all the lifecycle such as `HttpContextLifecycle`, `UniquePerRequestLifecycle`, `HttpContextLifecycle`, but did not work.

Here is the code I use:

```
  StructureMap.ObjectFactory.Configure(config =>
  config.For<IFoo>()
  .LifecycleIs(new StructureMap.Pipeline.HttpContextLifecycle())
  .Use(Foo1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prevent from changing the configuration of the container after the start-up phase of your application. Not only makes this your configuration hard to follow, as you are experiencing, it is extremely hard to get this right in a multi-threaded application.

This particular problem would be solved when you create one container instance per request. However, this can cause a severe performance hit, and would make it very hard to do simple registrations such as singletons. So, don't do that.

Instead, you should register a factory delegate that allows switching from `Foo` to `Foo1`:

```cs
container.Configure(r => r.For<IFoo>()
    .LifecycleIs(new HttpContextLifecycle())
    .Use(() =>
    {
        if (someCondition)
            return container.GetInstance<Foo>();  
        else
            return container.GetInstance<Foo1>();  
    }));
```